# Wordpress - Total User Count who only have posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display total number of user who only have posts at Wordpress. I can get all users by this query

```
<?php $user_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users;"); echo $user_count ?>
```

But for the user count only with posts, i think i might need to join another table, does anyone have snippets ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use wordpress, but if the schema at http://codex.wordpress.org/images/8/83/WP_27_dbsERD.png is close to the version that you are using, then you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts GROUP BY post_author
```

If you wanted to know which users had what number of posts you could do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_posts, u.user_login FROM 
wp_user u, wp_post p WHERE u.ID = p.post_author HAVING number_of_posts > 0;
```

Comment: thanks, i got very strange thing, if i run the first query at phpmyadmin, it shows correctly, but when i echo that query at php, it shows wrong, i don't know why, my syntax is like this

<?php $author_count=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts GROUP BY post_author"); echo $author_count ?>

Comment: I'm not familiar with the wordpress DB api. I would guess that either you need the $wpdb prefix on $wpdb->wp_posts like in your sample code or that the api does not like the GROUP BY clause for some reason

What is the strange thing - an error message or incorrect output?

Comment: it is incorrect output, and one thing i noticed is, at wp_post, there are other post_type also, which is page, so i changed the query like this SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts GROUP BY post_author AND post_type='post' , it only output 2 in my db, actually it have around like 30, is my query wrong ?

Comment: try 
<?php $author_count=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT post_author) FROM $wpdb->posts"); echo $author_count; ?>

Comment: btw, you should probably add the criteria. "and post_status = 'publish'"

Comment: you can use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY as windyjonas mentions. also, your syntax above should be `...WHERE post_type='post' GROUP BY post_author...` and not `...GROUP BY post_author AND post_type='post'`

Comment: thanks windyjonas, output is correct now. Thanks brian_d, sorry for being a noob.